# change div based on slider value

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, slider

Trying to trigger a function based on the position of a slider. I've tried several different ways. What am I missing here? Here's my code (below).
Html

```html
<div id="box">Box</div>
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
        <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="20" value="0" onchange="updateValue()">
        <div align="center" style="font-size:25px;">
            <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here's the CSS

```css
#box{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ffffff;}


input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #555555;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index:6000;
}
```

Here's the javascript

```js
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

function updateValue() {
  var rangeInput = document.getElementById("myRange").value
  if (rangeInput == 20) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'red'});

  }
  if (rangeInput == 40) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'blue'});

  }
    if (rangeInput == 60) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'pink'});

  }
    if (rangeInput == 80) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'green'});

  }
}
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to basically work. The only significant thing I did here was change `document.getElementById("myRange").value` to `document.getElementById("rangeInput").value`.

```js
// slider.oninput = function() {
//  output.innerHTML = this.value;
// }

function updateValue() {
  var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeInput").value
  if (rangeInput == 20) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'red'});

  }
  if (rangeInput == 40) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'blue'});

  }
    if (rangeInput == 60) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'pink'});

  }
    if (rangeInput == 80) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'green'});

  }
}
```

```css
#box{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ffffff;}


input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #555555;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index:6000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">Box</div>
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
  <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="20" value="0" oninput="updateValue()">
  <div align="center" style="font-size:25px;">
    <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
  </div>
</form>
```

Edit: changed `onchange="updateValue()"` to `oninput="updateValue()"` to have it update as it moves rather than on mouse up.

Comment: That works! Is there a way for it to change before mouse up? ...as you are sliding?

Comment: @RJ_OOOMS Please have a look at the edit. Note: I've never used this type of input before so I've no idea if there are other things to consider, but it seems to work in this example.

Comment: that works perfectly! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `slider.oninput` or put it at the bottom of the code because it overrides the onchange event.

```
function updateValue() {
  var rangeInput = document.getElementById("myRange").value
  if (rangeInput == 20) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'red'});

  }
  if (rangeInput == 40) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'blue'});

  }
    if (rangeInput == 60) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'pink'});

  }
    if (rangeInput == 80) {
    $("#box").css({'background':'green'});

  }
}

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```